# Prove the least upper bound and greatest lower bound of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that sup(A)=max(A)=$\frac{1}{2}$ , inf(A)= $-1$, and A has no minimum.

To show that $\frac{1}{2}$ is an upper bound, choose an arbitrary $a\in A$ and show that it is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{2}$.

There are two cases:

If n is even, how do you know $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \le \frac{1}{2}$?  If n is odd, how do you know $\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \le \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: By the way, in general, you should use weak inequalities $\leq$, not strict ones. (of course sometimes a strict one is true, but not always). My hint to you is what is $(-1)^n$ if $n$ is even? What about if $n$ is odd?

Comment: got it @peek-a-boo

Answer (score 0):

$x \leq |x|$ and $|(-1)^{n}|=1$. So $\frac {(-1)^{n}} n \leq \frac 1 n \leq \frac  1 2$ for all $n \geq 2$ (whether $n$ is even or odd). Now check that the inequality holds for $n=1$.